# get date from database and check if this date has passed

Tags: php

I have a database that holds jobs. It holds the job name and the expiration date. My database is **user_job(id, user_id, job_name, day, month, year)**. The form that used in order to insert expiration date for the job in database included 3 drop-down lists. One that the user selected day(values 1-31) then month(values jan to dec) and year(2014 to 2024). I use the following function to get server's date:

```
<?php

$server_date = date('Y-m-d');


$a = mysql_query("select * from `user_job` where `user_id`='$session_user_id'  ");

while($run_job = mysql_fetch_array($a)){

  $the_job_day = $run_job['day'];
  $the_job_month = $run_job['month'];
  $the_job_year = $run_job['year'];
}   

?>
```

My question is if there is a possibility now to compare server's date with the job's expiration date in my database. And if expiration date has passed just to echo a message, "expired". Is there a posibility to do this?

Comment: any idea please how can do it?

Comment: use `time()` for getting the current server time then get the time inserted in the database subtract it then its done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$the_job_time = strtotime($the_job_year .'-'. $the_job_month .'-'. $the_job_day);
$current_time = time();
if ($current_time > $the_job_time) {
    // the job have expired
}
```

But I would suggest to store the time differently in the database. There are a bunch of different date/time types you can use

Comment: this works perfect but I get a problem. Today is 2014-06-01 The above code works on me only if date is greater that 2014-06-19. Any idea why it is on day 19 and above?

Comment: Works for me. Please tell us what `$the_job_year .'-'. $the_job_month .'-'. $the_job_day` is in the case it doesn't work

Comment: i gave date 2 june 2014 and gives me number: 1401588000 and current date (today is 1 june 2014) gives number: 1401649815 which is greater than this gives me the 2 june 2014

Comment: It is impossible for `$the_job_year .'-'. $the_job_month .'-'. $the_job_day` to be `2 June 2014`. It will be a string containing at least two `-`.

Comment: But if $the_job_month is `june` you should really change how you store your dates. But to fix it change it to: `strtotime($the_job_day .' '. $the_job_month .' '. $the_job_year);`

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do it, by order of effectiveness :

1. Store your date as a `date` column in you database, then use a select statement to compare with `NOW()`
2. Get the current timestamps and the timestamps of you job, then compare them.
3. Use the `DateTime` class of PHP to use the `DateTime::diff()` method (see [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php))